# Obtain NEW Apple device token?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I am creating an app that allows the user to log out of the app and log in as different user if they want to. Is there any way to obtain a new device token from Apple once the new user logs in? Is there a way to force call the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't request a new device token. They expire from time to time, and only then will you get a new one (or if you have a different app with a different bundle id, the token will be different).

Create a function to handle didRegister and call that from didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken. Then use that function when you need to force the call.

Since users are logging in, pass the information with the device token to the server every time someone logs in and associate the user to the token on the server side.

Comment: It is not enough to pass new token to the server every time someone logs in. You will also need to remove the token from the server when a user logs out.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get a different device token. You need to remove the token from the backend when the user logs out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how it behaves in iOS7 and later, but prior to iOS7, all applications on the same device would get the same device token, and therefore what you ask is impossible. As of iOS7, each application gets its own device token, but I'm not sure if that token can change on consecutive registrations.

You can always force call the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` by calling `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes`, but usually you'll get the same device token.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to associate notifications with specific users, then as of iOS 10, you can try implementing a [NotificationService](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) extension to filter only those notifications associated with the currently authenticated user. While multiple users on the same device will be associated with the same device token at the server, the client will only display notifications for the current user - assuming that only one user at a time can be logged-in.

This approach also allows for having notifications that don't require authentication - just pass those through unaltered.

As mentioned above, you can force a request-response token update after user login by explicitly calling UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotification (Swift 3+). Then send that user+device token combination to your application server for use.